# API reply with multiple card errors

Tags: square-connect

Using the sandbox, if I generate multiple errors, like using 911 for the CVV and 01/40 for the date, and 99999 for the zip code, the reply has only one error in it. With all three of those error generating values, it returns only "Postal code check failed." Is there some way to get all errors back in a single post? What is the point of the JSON errors object being an array if only one error is included?

Comment: Are you only receiving a single error back when passing the nonce to the Charge endpoint? Or returned from cardNonceResponseReceived? My own testing on the Charge endpoint of this returned a `400` response with text = `{"errors":[{"category":"PAYMENT_METHOD_ERROR","code":"INVALID_EXPIRATION","detail":"Invalid card expiration date."},{"category":"PAYMENT_METHOD_ERROR","code":"VERIFY_AVS_FAILURE","detail":"Postal code check failed."},{"category":"PAYMENT_METHOD_ERROR","code":"VERIFY_CVV_FAILURE","detail":"Card verification code check failed."}]}`

Comment: It was to the customers/[customer_id]/cards endpoint, with a card_nonce. Evidently when a card nonce is generated, the card is not verified. {"errors":[{"category":"PAYMENT_METHOD_ERROR","code":"VERIFY_AVS_FAILURE","detail":"Postal code check failed."}]} 

Using the same endpoint, with a valid postal code, but 911 for the cvv and 01/40 for the expiration date, I still got only one error:

{"errors":[{"category":"PAYMENT_METHOD_ERROR","code":"INVALID_EXPIRATION","detail":"Invalid card expiration date."}]} (sorry I don't know how to get line returns in these comments.)